# C# Regex Match any text between tags including new lines

Tags: c#, regex, new-operator, lines

Here is my regex:

```
\[\[START\]\]\[\[OK\]\](.*?)\[\[END\]\]
```

I want to get any text contained in `[[START]][[OK]]` and `[[END]]`.

However when my text contains some `\r\n` characters, my regex doesn't match it.

How can it make it work?

Comment: Show your code you are using to execute it.

Answer (score 9):

Use single-line mode

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#Singleline

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure if this works for RegEx'es as well,but you could try using Environment.NewLine in stead of \r\n.