# Regex to extract "From" from the mail archive including name and newline

Tags: c#, regex

I am getting mail archive in below format and my goal is to parse them and store them in database. I have clubbed multiple samples in below example for demonstrating the data. The only thing to observe is "**From**" line

```
    From:         FirstName LastName <FirstName.MiddleName.LastName@someemail.com>
    In-Reply-To:  <fc7b93ca4dab.531f4e68@my.bcit.ca>
    -------------------------------------------------    
    From:         "FirstName. MiddleName =?iso-8859-1?b?TWFydO1uZXo=?= LastName"
                  <somemeail@something.otherthing.es> 
    Subject:      Re: Some Randome Data 
    In-Reply-To: <42043F8EC804DB48A3C4AF477195328F272CB9@exchange.something.local>
    -------------------------------------------------   
    From:         "FirstName MiddleName LastName" <LastName@someemail.com>
    Subject:      Some Randome Subject 
    -------------------------------------------------
    From:         "FirstName. MiddleName =?iso-8859-1?b?TWFydO1uZXo=?= LastName"
                  <somemeail@something.otherthing.es
                  > 
    Subject:      Re: Some Randome Data 
    In-Reply-To: <42043F8EC804DB48A3C4AF477195328F272CB9@exchange.something.local>
    -------------------------------------------------   
    From:         "FirstName. MiddleName =?iso-8859-1?b?TWFydO1uZXo=?= LastName"
                  <
                  somemeail@something.otherthing.es
                  > 
    Subject:      Re: Some Randome Data 
    In-Reply-To: <42043F8EC804DB48A3C4AF477195328F272CB9@exchange.something.local>
```

So far I have noticed that all the headers except "**From**" are always consistent and they always appear on the same line however "**From**" is giving me really hard time.

I am using following Regular Expression in my C# code to extract "From".

```
match = Regex.Match(msg, @"(?<=From:)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

I have also tried below expression but it messes up other records.

```
match = Regex.Match(msg, @"(?<=From:).*.\s*.*\s*(>)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

I would like to do below things
- Grab the line which starts with From: but do not capture it i.e. (?<=From:) 
- Now keep going until you reach ">" and it must include everything like whitespace, newline

I am struggling to come up this expression.

I have already gone thru [regex-that-matches-a-newline-n-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175053/regex-that-matches-a-newline-n-in-c-sharp), [c-sharp-regex-match-any-text-between-tags-including-new-lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179116/c-sharp-regex-match-any-text-between-tags-including-new-lines) but wasn't able to implement it in my code.

Complete sample code

```
    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                foreach (var demoText in TestData())
                {
                    var match = Regex.Match(demoText, @"(?<=From:).*", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        string fromField = match.Value.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ");

                        // Found From - extract the email address
                        match = Regex.Match(fromField, @"(?<=<)+[^<>]+(?=>)+", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
                        Console.WriteLine("Email Address:" + match.Value);

                        // Extract the name
                        match = Regex.Match(fromField, @".*(?=<)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
                        Console.WriteLine("Name:" + match.Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("*** Match not found in data: " + demoText);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("All done, press any key to close.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        static IEnumerable<string> TestData()
        {
            return @"
From:         FirstName LastName <FirstName.MiddleName.LastName@someemail.com>
In-Reply-To:  <fc7b93ca4dab.531f4e68@my.bcit.ca>ñ


From:         ""FirstName. MiddleName =?iso-8859-1?b?TWFydO1uZXo=?= LastName""
                <somemeail@something.otherthing.es> 
Subject:      Re: Some Randome Data 
In-Reply-To: <42043F8EC804DB48A3C4AF477195328F272CB9@exchange.something.local>ñ


From:         ""FirstName MiddleName LastName"" <LastName@someemail.com>
Subject:      Some Randome Subject ñ

From:         ""FirstName. MiddleName =?iso-8859-1?b?TWFydO1uZXo=?= LastName""
                <somemeail@something.otherthing.es
                > 
Subject:      Re: Some Randome Data 
In-Reply-To: <42043F8EC804DB48A3C4AF477195328F272CB9@exchange.something.local>ñ


From:         ""FirstName. MiddleName =?iso-8859-1?b?TWFydO1uZXo=?= LastName""
                <
                somemeail@something.otherthing.es
                > 
Subject:      Re: Some Randome Data 
In-Reply-To: <42043F8EC804DB48A3C4AF477195328F272CB9@exchange.something.local>
".Split('ñ').Select(item => item.Trim());
```

Comment: Please give your question a title. Currently you just list tags.

Comment: Are these outlook items?

Comment: They are LISTSERV archives.

Comment: @ndd - good edit on the title. You changed it when I had it open for a change :)  abatishchev's wasn't being unfriendly. There's a site policy on it. See [Can we prevent titles with an unnecessary tag in them?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103563/173448)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the name part can not contains any angle bracket you can use:

```
(?<=\bFrom:)[^>]+>
```

Note: You don't need a particular option to make it work except the case insensitive option if needed.

If you want to do the same and extract names and emails in one shot, you can use this:

```
\bFrom:\s*(?:"(?<name>[^"]+)"|(?<name>[^<]+?))\s+<\s*(?<email>[^>]+?)\s*>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(?<=From:)((?:(?!>).)*)>
```

Try this.Do not forget to set `s` or `DOTALL` flag.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kM7rT8/14

Comment: When I am running the same code in C# it is not able to find the match. [Output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/R5c9U.png)

Comment: @ndd have you set the flag?

Comment: @ndd You'll need to change `RegexOptions.Multiline` to `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

Comment: @juharr I did try both of them :) however I got the same result

Comment: @vks My apologies I think I was wrong, I just re-tested and this time when I specified Singleline option it worked correctly. I have up voted your answer.

Comment: @vks I can't ever thank you enough for showing me regex101.com :) still I will try, thanks from bottom of my heart for showing me this website.